# Powershell Flatten Directory Function - Problems with filename collisions

Tags: windows, powershell, file

I am writing a function in PowerShell 7 that flattens a directory.

It's ideally supposed to:

1. Copy / Move everything to a temp directory (Depending on whether a destination was supplied)
2. Rename all files that have identical filenames with a _XX numerical suffix (Padding controlled by a parameter)
3. Move everything back to the root of the original directory, or the destination directory supplied.

[Here is the gist.](https://gist.github.com/visusys/477e811b04eacd468af67b14438f356c)

Here is the relevant code, without documentation to save space as it's a long one:

```
function Merge-FlattenDirectory {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [ValidateScript({
                if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $_)) {
                    throw [System.ArgumentException] "Path does not exist." 
                }
                if ((Test-IsSensitiveWindowsPath -Path $_ -Strict).IsSensitive) {
                    throw [System.ArgumentException] "Path supplied is a protected OS directory."
                }
                return $true
            })]
        [Alias("source", "input", "i")]
        [string]
        $SourcePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias("destination", "dest", "output", "o")]
        [string]
        $DestinationPath = $null,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Switch]
        $Force,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
        [int32]
        $DuplicatePadding = 2
    )

    begin {

        # Trim trailing backslashes and initialize a new temporary directory.
        $SourcePath         = $SourcePath.TrimEnd('\')
        $DestinationPath    = $DestinationPath.TrimEnd('\')
        $TempPath           = (New-TempDirectory).FullName

        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $TempPath
        
        # Escape $SourcePath so we can use wildcards.
        $Source = [WildcardPattern]::Escape($SourcePath)

        # If there is no $DestinationPath supplied, we flatten only the SourcePath. 
        # Thus, set DestinationPath to be the same as the SourcePath.
        if (!$DestinationPath) {
            $DestinationPath = $SourcePath

            # Since there is no destination supplied, we move everything to a temporary 
            # directory for further processing.
            Move-Item -Path $Source'\*' -Destination $TempPath -Force

        }else{

            # We need to perform some parameter validation on DestinationPath:

            # Make sure the passed Destination is not a file
            if(Test-Path -LiteralPath $DestinationPath -PathType Leaf){
                throw [System.IO.IOException] "Please provide a valid directory, not a file."
            }

            # Make sure the passed Destination is a validly formed Windows path.
            if(!(Confirm-ValidWindowsPath -Path $DestinationPath -Container)){
                throw [System.IO.IOException] "Invalid Destination Path. Please provide a valid directory."
            }

            # Make sure the passed Destination is not in a protected or sensitive OS location.
            if((Test-IsSensitiveWindowsPath -Path $DestinationPath -Strict).IsSensitive){
                throw [System.IO.IOException] "The destination path is, or resides in a protected operating system directory."
            }

            # Since a destination was supplied, we copy everything to a new temp directory 
            # instead of moving everything. We want the source directory to remain untouched.

            # Robocopy seems to be the most performant here.
            # Robocopy on Large Dataset:  ~789ms - ~810ms
            # Copy-Item on Large Dataset: ~1203ms - ~1280ms
            #
            # Copy-Item -Path $Source'\*' -Destination $TempPath -Force -Recurse
            Robocopy $Source $TempPath /COPYALL /B /E /R:0 /W:0 /NFL /NDL /NC /NS /NP /MT:48

            # Create the destination directory now, ready for population in the process block.
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $DestinationPath

        }

        # Grab all files as an Array of FileInfo Objects
        $AllFiles = [IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($TempPath).GetFiles('*', 'AllDirectories')
        
        # Initialize hashtable to store duplicate files
        $Duplicates = @{}
    }

    process {

        ##
        # $Stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        # 
        
        # Iterate over all files
        foreach ($File in $AllFiles) {

            # If our $Duplicates hashtable already contains the current filename, we have a duplicate.
            if ($Duplicates.Contains($File.Name)) {

                # Rename the duplicate file by appending a numerical index to the end of the file.
                $PathTemp = Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $File
                $RenamedFile = Rename-Item -LiteralPath $PathTemp.PSPath -PassThru -NewName ('{0}_{1}{2}' -f @(
                    $File.BaseName
                    $Duplicates[$File.Name].ToString().PadLeft($DuplicatePadding, '0')
                    $File.Extension
                ))

                # Increment the duplicate counter and pass $File down to be moved.
                $Duplicates[$File.Name]++
                $File = $RenamedFile

            } else {

                # No duplicates were detected. Add a value of 1 to the duplicates 
                # hashtable to represent the current file. Pass $File down to be moved.
                $PathTemp = Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $File
                $Duplicates[$File.Name] = 1
                $File = $PathTemp
            }

            # If Force is specified, we don't have to worry about duplicate files,
            # as the operation will overwrite every file with a duplicate filename
            if($Force){

                # Move the file to its appropriate destination. (Force)
                Move-Item -LiteralPath $File -Destination $DestinationPath -Force
            } else {
                try {

                    # Move the file to its appropriate destination. (Non-Force)
                    Move-Item -LiteralPath $File -Destination $DestinationPath -ErrorAction Stop
                } catch {
                    # Warn the user that files were skipped because of duplicate filenames.
                    Write-Warning "File already exists in the destination folder. Skipping this file."
                }
            }

            # Return each file to the pipeline.
            # $File
        }

        # $Stopwatch.Stop()
        # Write-Host "`$Stopwatch.Elapsed:            " $Stopwatch.Elapsed -ForegroundColor Green  
        # Write-Host "`$Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:" $Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds -ForegroundColor Green
        # Write-Host "`$Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks:       " $Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks -ForegroundColor Green 
    }

    end {
        
    }
}

# Merge-FlattenDirectory "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Testing\Test" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Testing\TestFlat" -Force
```

The function works great for the most part, but there is a major problem I didn't anticipate. The code is vulnerable to naming collisions. Here's a problematic directory structure:

(Root directory to be flattened is `C:\Users\username\Desktop\Testing\Test`)

```
    Directory: C:\Users\username\Desktop\Testing\Test

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           11/4/2021 10:03 PM        1552565 1088_p_01.jpg
-a---           11/4/2021 10:03 PM        1552565 1088_p_02.jpg
-a---           11/4/2021 10:03 PM        1552565 1088_p_03.jpg

    Directory: C:\Users\username\Desktop\Testing\Test\Folder

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           11/4/2021 10:03 PM        1552565 1088_p_03.jpg
-a---           11/4/2021 10:03 PM        1552565 1088_p.jpg

    Directory: C:\Users\username\Desktop\Testing\Test\Testing

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           11/4/2021 10:03 PM        1552565 1088_p_01.jpg
-a---           11/4/2021 10:03 PM        1552565 1088_p.jpg
```

If I run the function to flatten `C:\Users\username\Desktop\Testing\Test` I get only six files instead of seven in the destination folder. The folder is missing the second `1088_p.jpg`. I can verify this by going to my temp directory and looking at what's left:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\DdtElMvSoXbJf\Testing\1088_p.jpg` is still in temp.

Anyway, If you're still with me after all this, I thank you generously for reading.

I really need to refactor the function in a way that accounts for this edge-case and I can't figure out how to do it at all gracefully. I could desperately use some help or guidance from someone that can point me in the right direction. I've been working on this function for awhile now and I'd really like to wrap it up.

Many, many thanks.

### Edit:

I have a working solution now. I added an additional layer of duplication checks, and moved the actual renaming of the file further down.

Here's the revised code (Only relevant portion included):

```
# Iterate over all files
        foreach ($File in $AllFiles) {

            # If our $Duplicates hashtable already contains the current filename, we have a duplicate.
            if ($Duplicates.Contains($File.Name)) {

                # Create a new name for the file by appending a numerical index to the end of the filename.
                $PathTemp = Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $File
                $NewName = ('{0}_{1}{2}' -f @(
                    $File.BaseName
                    $Duplicates[$File.Name].ToString().PadLeft($DuplicatePadding, '0')
                    $File.Extension
                ))

                # Check if our new name collides with any other filenames in $Duplicates. If so, create 
                # another new name by appending an additional numeric index to the end of the filename.
                $DuplicateCount = 1
                while ($Duplicates[$NewName]) {
                    $NewName = ('{0}_{1}{2}' -f @(
                        [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($NewName)
                        $DuplicateCount.ToString().PadLeft($DuplicatePadding, '0')
                        [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($NewName)
                    ))

                    Write-Warning $DuplicateCount.ToString().PadLeft($DuplicatePadding, '0')

                    $DuplicateCount++

                    # If we're at a depth of 8, throw. Something is obviously wrong.
                    if ($DuplicateCount -ge 8) {
                        throw [System.Exception] "Duplicate count reached limit."
                        break
                    }
                }

                # Finally, rename the file with our new name.
                $RenamedFile = Rename-Item -LiteralPath $PathTemp.PSPath -PassThru -NewName $NewName

                # Increment the duplicate counters and pass $File down to be moved.
                $Duplicates[$File.Name]++
                $Duplicates[$NewName]++
                $File = $RenamedFile
                
            } else {

                # No duplicates were detected. Add a value of 1 to the duplicates 
                # hashtable to represent the current file. Pass $File down to be moved.
                $PathTemp = Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $File
                $Duplicates[$File.Name] = 1
                $File = $PathTemp
            }

            # If Force is specified, we don't have to worry about duplicate files,
            # as the operation will overwrite every file with a duplicate filename
            if($Force){

                # Move the file to its appropriate destination. (Force)
                Move-Item -LiteralPath $File -Destination $DestinationPath -Force
            } else {
                try {

                    # Move the file to its appropriate destination. (Non-Force)
                    Move-Item -LiteralPath $File -Destination $DestinationPath -ErrorAction Stop
                } catch {
                    # Warn the user that files were skipped because of duplicate filenames.
                    Write-Warning "File already exists in the destination folder. Skipping this file."
                }
            }

            # Return each file to the pipeline.
            $File
        }
```

Comment: I would use `"{0}_{1:D$DuplicatePadding}{2}"` as format and remove the `PadLeft()` method which does nothing. i.e. `"test".PadLeft(2, '0')` return `test`. For number format options see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#how-do-i-control-the-number-of-integral-digits).

Comment: It works fine for me. I'm just padding numbers. Feedback noted though. I'll check out your link now.